# Regarding definition of Borel Sets is $ \sigma $ ring of sets

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures, measurable-sets

I am self studying Measure and Integration from  book Hari Bercovici,  Arlen Brown and I need help in proving definition that Borel sets is a $ \sigma $  ring of sets . 
Authors defines A ring of sets as follows - A collection C of subsets of a set X is called Ring if - 
1. It is closed wrt to formation of union. 
2. It is closed wrt formation of differences ie  if A and B belongs to C then A\ B also belongs to C. 
Then  if  some addition conditions hold then it is called  $ \sigma $  ring of sets . 
I cannot prove   2 nd condition of ring in case of Borel sets. 
Definition of ring of Borel sets in X - 
In any metric space (X, d) ,  the topology G , that is,  collection of all open sets in X ,  generates a $  \sigma  $ ring  of sets called ring of borel sets. 
So,  I want to ask  how does topology generates a ring ie if  P and Q  belongs to Collection C how to prove P\ Q also belongs to C. 
An example which I thought  - take eucledian metric on Real line and (0, 5 and (1, 2)  are open.  Then (0, 5) \ (1, 2)  is (0, 1] union [2, 5)  is not open but it is contained into open sets but these Sets  doesn't belong to C. 
I am really confused how to prove 2 nd condition . please help.

Comment: See the word "generate"?  Your $\sigma$-ring is more than just the open sets.  It is the least $sigma$-ring containing all open sets.

Comment: @ GEdgar got your point ie it is a least  $ \sigma $ ring containing all open sets.  But I have to prove it is actually a $ \sigma $ ring.

Comment: @ GEdgar to prove it is a $ \sigma ring I am only struct on the 2 nd  condition regarding proving that it is a ring ie   difference of two sets will also belong to this collection.  My doubt was that the difference set could not be open set as I gave a specific example.  Perhaps I am wrong in interpretating some basic concept which is required in proving condition 2. I am really struct. Please provide some insight how to prove it a ring.

Comment: By definition, the $\sigma$-ring generated by any set $\mathcal U$ of sets, is the smallest $\sigma$-ring that contains $\mathcal U$. In particular, it is by definition a $\sigma$-ring. Your 'counterexample' is just an example of a *Borel-set* which is not open.